# Syntax of a function call that accepts a 2D list in C#

Tags: c#, list, 2d

I got a bit confused. A program has a 2D list:

```
List<int>field = new List<int>();
List<List>fieldSets = new List<List<int>>;
```

Now I want to write a few functions that accept fieldSets as input and output an int, or update fieldSets entirely.

My confusion is the proper way of writing a function call for a 2D int List:

```
private int FindFirstCrossFieldMark (List<List< i>>)  //<== ???
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it

```
List<List<int>> fieldSets = new List<List<int>>(); 
// or var fieldSets = new List<List<int>>();  would be enough

private int FindFirstCrossFieldMark (List<List<int>> listOflist)
{
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a generic function instead of defining the list earlier, as the part where i have this in a class library and i rather not expose the fieldsets ?.